# How can I resolve the null object reference in c#

Tags: c#

I want to print all the products with a price between 10 and 50 euro.
I have created 2 products in main and I call the method from the class Product in order to make the verification.But it gives me the else branch everytime, "No products".I understand what I'm doing wrong, I create an object reference from the class Product, then I call the method but it gives me the wrong output because in the method I create another object and for this object this price is 0 so it shows me that thing.
But how can I resolve this?
Here there are the classes:
the product class:

```
 class Product
{
    public int ProductId;
    public string SKU;
    public string Name;
    public decimal Price;
    public string Description;
    public string Producer;
    public virtual decimal GetPrice()
    {
        return Price;
    }
    public virtual String GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    public void PrintPrice()
    {
        Product f = new Product();
        if (f.GetPrice() > 10 && f.GetPrice() < 50)

            Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}", f.GetName());

        else
            Console.WriteLine("No products priced between 10 and 50 lei.");
    }
    public Product() { }
```

the main where I ve been creating the objects:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product f = new Food(1, "green", "Papa", 15, "Good Quality", "Sana");
        Product f1 = new Food(2, "white", "Papa1", 45, "Bad Quality", "Ariel");

        f.PrintPrice();
        f1.PrintPrice();
    }
```

and I have also the food class but it inherits only the Product class so it's not relevant here.So what can I do?Thank you.

Comment: if (f.GetPrice() > 10 && f.GetPrice() < 50) should be: if (this.GetPrice() > 10 && this.GetPrice() < 50), removing f declaration.

Comment: Replace `f` by `this`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Or remove `f.` completely.

Comment: Sure, just to give a hint what happens @DavidG. And I like to include the scope in my calls.

Comment: I don't understand why I received so many bad votes.

Answer (score 3):

```
   public void PrintPrice()
    {
        Product f = new Product();
       ....
    }
```

At the moment, f is a new Product without any properties (including no price)

You should do something like

```
public void PrintPrice()
{
    if (this.GetPrice() > 10 && this.GetPrice() < 50)

        Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}", this.GetName());

    else
        Console.WriteLine("No products priced between 10 and 50 lei.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not assign a value to the Price, so it's 0 and then you have the "No products"..try to assign a value to the product first